# How to identify fields from INCLUDETEXT?

Tags: vba, ms-word

With VBA Microsoft Word, I work on documents that use lot of INCLUDETEXT and MERGEFIELD.

I would like identify  the MERGEFIELD fields from the main document and the MERGEFIELD fields from the INCLUDETEXT documents.

```
Sub listAllFields()
Dim fld As Field
Dim oStory As Object

    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        For Each fld In oStory.Fields
            Debug.Print fld.Type, fld.Code.Text, fld.Parent.Name
        Next fld
    Next oStory

End Sub
```

`fld.Parent.Name` return always the main document name.

For example, I have in my main document 2 fields: 1 INCLUDETEXT and 1 MERGEFIELD. In the enclosed document I have 3 MERGEFIELD. When I enumerate all the fields of my main documents with the code I propose, I will access 5 fields. How to know if a MERGEFIELD field comes from the main document or if it is inherited from the document included by INCLUDETEXT?

Comment: INCLUDETEXT fields *always* contain the source document's name...

Comment: Thanks, I know what information my code is sending me back and the example may be wrong.

So I will try to clarify my question.

For example, I have in my main document 2 fields: 1 INCLUDETEXT and 1 MERGEFIELD. In the enclosed document I have 3 MERGEFIELD. 

When I enumerate all the fields of my main documents with the code I propose, I will access 5 fields. 

How to know if a MERGEFIELD field comes from the main document or if it is inherited from the document included by INCLUDETEXT?

Comment: You should put that additional information in the question itself, not in a comment.